# Is it safe to login as the same user from different client in the same time in MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

In a traditional Java client-server application, I created one MySQL user in a server.  Then, multiple clients are connected to MySQL as that user.  Is this safe?  I've encountered some random `Communication Link Failure` exceptions in several clients but haven't decided to investigate yet because they disappear when I closed and reopened the application.

Comment: MySQL is a multi-user database by design. I'm not sure why connecting multiple times would be an issue so long as you're below the connection limit, and that is adjustable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. Yes, you can connect multiple times to a server with the same user, it is often used in production servers for load balancing purposes, where many servers access a database, or many services on a server access a database at the same time.

The reason I also say no, is that if you start to open up TOO MANY connections to the MySQL server, it will cause issues with concurrency and too many connections open.

Comment: Do you know how to pool connections from multiple clients in a pure database server to avoid too many connections?

Answer (score 2):

Two things to consider: 1) the number of connections your MySQL server can support and 2) application transactions managements.  #1 is external to your application, determined by your MySQL server and/or your network setup, modern connection pooling goes a long way to help with that.  #2 is internal to your application and has to do with how you begin/commit/rollback transactions.  More connections you have => higher likelihood there will be multiple users operating on the same tables => more careful you'll have to be about your transaction management.

Comment: Transaction is not distributed.  Each client should have their isolated transactions.  Will using the same user in the same time mess up with the integrity of transaction?

Comment: Not at all as long as TX management is setup correctly and all transactions are demarcated. What kind of transaction management are you using?

Comment: No special transaction management, just begin transaction, `try-finally`, and commit transaction in every DAO methods.

Comment: That should work just fine. Are you using Spring by any chance? If you are, there is a really handy `@Transactional` annotation that basically does the commit/rollback for you. JPA also has a similar annotation. In the end it accomplishes the same thing as doing it manually in try/catch/finally, just eliminates the needs for all the extra code.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes, it should be.

Longer answer: You might want to have a look at you MySQL server configuration, specifically max connections.

Depending on your use case, I would also suggest you look into Connection pooling (javax.sql.DataSource). [Apache DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/) is popular. EVEN if your application typically only use one connection at a time, the pooling implementation will be able to maintain your connection(s) in a live, and connected state (ok, technically it can test and re-open a connection if needed before your app uses it).

Dirty secret of production systems: things go wrong. You would do well to cater for it.

Good luck!

Comment: One more thing to consider is the connection timeout settings: both the server and the client has a value for this. Essentially it kicks in when a connection appears to be idle. You might want to tweak this a bit also (but be care full ,each connection consumes RAM - don't want to many hanging around doing nada)

Comment: Each client will have to create at least one connection. Does MySQL support connection pooling in a pure database server?

Comment: Hi David - not sure what you mean by "pure database server"? The connection pooling happens on the client side. So a lib like DBCP will maintain a pool of ready-to-use connections (min/max size configurable). Take note of the max pool size, since your server will need to be able to handle max-size * number-of-clients connections.